# Sink restart on failure without stopping the pipeline

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

today I decided to transform my little script, based on `gst-launch`, into a real Python/GStreamer application, in order to add some features.

I developed a little program which send the audio from my microphone to both Icecast (`shout2send`) and local storage (`filesink`) thanks to `tee`.

Sometimes `shout2send` can halt, due to network problems. I would like to restart this element every N seconds until the connection is back, without stopping the pipeline, because the local audio file should not be impacted from network conditions.

Here's what I tried:

1. stopping/starting the pipeline one second after the network error (result: streaming works, local file is truncated)
2. unlink from `tee`, set `shout2send` state to `NULL` and removing it from pipeline (result: GStreamer critical errors like `Trying to dispose element ... but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state`)
3. Trying to understand how to use pads in this case (result: same as above, but with more code involved)

What should I do?

Here's how my code looks like :

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gst
# [...]

def message_handler(bus, message):
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        if message.src == shout2send:
            pass # TODO: restart the element
        else:
            print(message.parse_error())
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            exit(1)
    else:
        print(message.type)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
message_bus = pipeline.get_bus()
message_bus.add_signal_watch()
message_bus.connect('message', message_handler)

# [...]
tee.link(queue0)
queue0.link(filesink)
tee.link(queue1)
queue1.link(shout2send)
```

**Update (9/12/15)**: non-working code added + log

I tried to follow ["Dynamically changing the pipeline" fro GStreamer doc](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html), but my code doesn't work.

```
def event_probe(pad, info, *args):
    Gst.Pad.remove_probe(pad, info)
    queue1.unlink(shout2send)
    tee.unlink(queue1)
    pipeline.remove(shout2send)
    pipeline.remove(queue1)
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

def message_handler(bus, message):
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        if message.src == shout2send:
            pad = queue1.get_static_pad('src')
            pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, event_probe, None)
        else:
            print(message.parse_error())
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            exit(1)
    else:
        print(message.type)
```

Here's what I see if I run my script with `GST_DEBUG=3` and I restart Icecast while streaming:

```
[...]
0:00:02.142033258  5462 0x55e414d900a0 WARN                  shout2 gstshout2.c:674:gst_shout2send_render:<shout2send> error: shout_send() failed: Socket error
0:00:02.658137998  5462 0x55e414d90140 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop:<pulsesrc> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:02.658169752  5462 0x55e414d90140 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop:<pulsesrc> error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
(GLib.Error('Internal data flow error.', 'gst-stream-error-quark', 1), 'gstbasesrc.c(2943): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPulseSrc:pulsesrc:\nstreaming task paused, reason error (-5)')
0:00:02.658628129  5462 0x7f6ba8002a30 WARN                audiosrc gstaudiosrc.c:244:audioringbuffer_thread_func:<pulsesrc> error reading data -1 (reason: Success), skipping segment
```

Comment: what do you mean doesnt work(I havent analyzed it though)? some logs?

Comment: @otopolsky log added; it looks like the pipeline stops to work for an `Internal data flow error`

Comment: this looks like something wasnt connected .. check with `GST_DEBUG=3,default:4`

Comment: also are you working with EOS as stated in the dynamic pipe change example?

Comment: also you should set NULL to element before removing..

Comment: @otopolsky It looks like that EOS is needed if you don't want to lose data and there are other elements in the pipeline: this is not my case, because shout2send is dead and I don't mind if there are data in queue1. If I set theirs states to NULL before removing and I run the application `GST_DEBUG=3,default:4` nothing changes (same error).

Comment: ok so no additional info when you add default:4? .. I noticed `   tee.unlink(shout2send)` .. shouldnt it be tee.unlink(queue1) ?

Comment: @otopolsky no additional info with default:4. Yes, you're right I fixed it and the last two log lines are disappeared (log and code updated), but it still doesn't work

Comment: now when I think of it, shouldnt you block the pads before tee? because having one branch of tee running and not the other seems weird.. but I dont know what will happen to the file if you block probles..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to otopolsky's comments I did it :)

What I did wrong:

1. elements must be set to `NULL`: this is very important
2. `oggmux` must stay after `tee`, on both sub-pipelines: otherwise Icecast will list the stream without be able to serve it. Do the same for `opusenc`

Advice:

1. Is not necessary to unlink every element you don't need: just break where needed
2. Is not necessary to remove from the pipeline every element you don't need: keep them if you think to reuse them

Final code (reconnection works correctly and independently from local encoding/recording):

```
def event_probe2(pad, info, *args):
    Gst.Pad.remove_probe(pad, info.id)
    tee.link(opusenc1)
    opusenc1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    oggmux1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    queue1.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    shout2send.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

def reconnect():
    pad = tee.get_static_pad('src_1')
    pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, event_probe2, None)

def event_probe(pad, info, *args):
    Gst.Pad.remove_probe(pad, info.id)
    tee.unlink(opusenc1)
    opusenc1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    oggmux1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    queue1.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    shout2send.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(interval, reconnect)
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

def message_handler(bus, message):
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        if message.src == shout2send:
            pad = tee.get_static_pad('src_1')
            pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, event_probe, None)
        else:
            print(message.parse_error())
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            exit(1)
    else:
        print(message.type)
```

Minor problems:

1. I use `tee.get_static_pad('src_1')`, but I think I could get the src id somewhere, instead of using a fixed value
2. Probably the whole thing could be written in a better form (but this is my first program with Python+Gstreamer and it works, so I'm fine with it)
3. In order to avoid data loss I call `pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)` one second after `pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())`, but I still get messages like `WARN audiosrc gstaudiosrc.c:244:audioringbuffer_thread_func:<pulsesrc> error reading data -1 (reason: Success), skipping segment`

Code: https://github.com/ViGLug/libre-streaming